# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number in C#

Tags: c#, oracle

I tried to change the capital letters to non capital but still giving me same errors.

Line of error is happening in `GridView1_RowUpdating`

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":telephone", txtEdittelephone.Text);
```

Comment: On which line is the exception occuring?

Comment: at the last lines ,specifically at this line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Comment: Please put effort into being more clear and specific. Is the error occuring in the `RowUpdating` or `RowDeleting` event? Kindly edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, its in the RowUpdating Event.I just got tired its 04 morning and I haven't go to bed yet.

Comment: No problem. In the future please only post code relevant to the problem you're experiencing. There's no need to show us all your code, and it complicates the troubleshooting process. Sleep well :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Oracle (which I assume this is), but I believe `telephone:=telephone` should be `telephone=:telephone`.

The error seems to be occurring with your SQL code, so most of your other posted code is irrelevant.

Comment: Unlike the OP, it's only 11:28 PM here. I've still got another 4.5 hours before I'll be as tired as they are! :)

Comment: there were two like this telephone and user, I did updated it but still giving same error!